# geth installation with homebrew stuck at Checking out tag v1.7.0

Tags: go-ethereum, installation, homebrew

i am a complete newbie in the ethereum space and is trying to install geth on my mac using homebrew

after the step : 
==> Cloning https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum.git

the process has stuck at :
==> Checking out tag v1.7.

it has been for hours and i don't know how to trouble shoot, any help would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and here was what worked for me:

Cancel (control + c) at `==> Checking out tag v1.7.x`

Clean existing library
`rm -rf https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum.git /Users/YOUR_USERNAME/Library/Caches/Homebrew/ethereum--git`

Clone new library
`git clone https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum.git /Users/YOUR_USERNAME/Library/Caches/Homebrew/ethereum--git`

Make a new build
run `cd /Users/YOUR_USERNAME/Library/Caches/Homebrew/ethereum--git && make geth`

After this has completed run `/Users/YOUR_USERNAME/Library/Caches/Homebrew/ethereum--git/build/bin/geth` to launch geth. Hope this works.

You can also run `alias geth="/Users/YOUR_USERNAME/Library/Caches/Homebrew/ethereum--git/build/bin/geth"` to allow you to run geth via command `geth` in the future.

Comment: Got the same issue with v1.8.3.
You might want to consider running `make all` (instead of only `make geth`), and if you do that, you might also want to consider adding the /Users/YOUR_USERNAME/Library/Caches/Homebrew/ethereum--git/build/bin/ to your path.